# Limit the number of Multivalue parameter selections SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report with a parameter with about 12 multivalue parameters. Is there a way to select 5 parameters and when selecting the 6th parameter displaying 5 is the limit ??

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around , you could try using a combination of a visibility expression to count the parameters chosen and a separate text box with a warning message, such as :

=IIF(Count(Parameters!XYZ.Value(0),"DataSet1") > 5 , "too many parameters selected", "ok")

and using a variation of the expression to hide / show your original report.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to give immediate feedback when the limit is exceeded. One option would be to show a message once they click the `View Report` button. It's a bit of a workaround, but you would have to have the dataset return no rows. Then for the message, you could either have a texbox with conditional visibility somewhere on the report OR you could use the `NoRowsMessage` property on a table to show the appropriate message.

If you have a more complex situation such as multiple parameters, you can just add in more conditional logic to the dataset and message to check if all the conditions are met and which message should appear.